# Trouble reading CSV into Monetdb using R

Tags: r, monetdb, rstudio-server

I am trying to read a CSV file into a Monetdb data base using R Studio server. The CSV file is 13 columns, and a few hundred thousand rows, consisting of 1 column of strings, and 12 columns of integers. When I use the monet.read.csv function:

```
monet.read.csv(     #Function
  db ,              #Data Base  
  pde ,             #CSV Name
  paste0( 'pde' , substr( year , 3 , 4 ) ) , #Name of new table
  nrows = sapply( pde , countLines )         #Rows in new table
)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
>    Unable to execute statement 'COPY 10000001 OFFSET 2 RECORDS INTO pde08 FROM '/home/jamie/R/x86_64-pc->linux-gnu-library/3.1/Jamie_...'.
>   ' from line 1 field 13 not inserted, expecting type int'.

I have tried using the data.table package and dbWriteTable function, so know that Monetdb itself is working. Does anyone know what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: Could you show a reproducible example? Try extracting a few lines from the file and posting them (according to your error message, the error occurs on line 1, so the first couple lines should do it). You should also show the code you use (what database are you inserting them into?)

Comment: I second that, @DavidRobinson

Comment: @HannesMühleisen Jamie is having trouble at [line 269 of this script](https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd/blob/master/Basic%20Stand%20Alone%20Medicare%20Claims%20Public%20Use%20Files/2008%20-%20import%20all%20csv%20files%20into%20monetdb.R#L269)

Comment: Jamie- please try in base R instead of R studio?  if that doesn't work, you'll have to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), because the script you are having trouble with has been tested on windows and *nix and works fine for me

Comment: Jamie- please edit your question to clarify what the `data.table` package has to do with anything?  and also please confirm that these scripts run correctly on your computer -- https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd/tree/master/MonetDB  thanks!